# Unable to get Authorisation Token in Jmeter

Tags: oauth, jmeter

I'm trying to get an authorization token in Jmeter, as far as I can see everything is correct, but I end up with an error saying

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Please enter the correct email and password combination."}
```

It's working perfectly for me when I do it in Postman, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

In postman it looks as follows:

[image: Postman Body]

[image: Postman Headers]

My setup in Jmeter looks as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to tick `Encode` box so `+` sign in your "username" would be transformed into `%2B`

---

Also given your request works fine in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) like:

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature:

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start
2. Prepare Postman for recording. It would be sufficient to run it providing [`--proxy-server argument`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md#--proxy-serveraddressport):

   ```
    postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
   ```
3. Run your request in Postman
4. JMeter will capture it under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, ticking the Encode box solved the problem